# Initializing a SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, oncreate

DatabaseHelper class's onCreate method is called when db.getWritableDatabase() or db.getReadableDatabase() is called. So, whenever use the dbhelper for the first time, onCreate will be called at that time.
I want my database to be called whenever the app is started for the first time instead of first use of dbhelper.

Comment: What prevents you from calling e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` when the app is starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your Db Class in applicaion Class ....

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    private static AppController mInstance;
    private DatabaseManager databaseManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        databaseManager = new DataBaseManger(mInstance);


    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

}
```

Declare the Application Class in Android Manifest...

```
<application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

     ---------------------------------------
     ----------------------------------------
   -------------------------------------------

   </application>
```

Comment: public DatabaseHandler(Context context) { super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); this.context = context; }            this won't call onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

> I want my database to be called whenever the app is started for the first time instead of first use of dbhelper.

Create a Custom Application class  and Initialize your database in Application's `onCreate()` method. This will ensure your database will be initialized before any `Activity` launch. Because Application class run before any Activity launch.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize your Database here 

  }
}
```

Define you Application Class in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <application
    android:name="com.example.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/BaseTheme">
    ...................
    ...................
     </application>
```

Comment: should i add this code ?, DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
db.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Just call `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: but this won't call oncreate method of dbhelper

Comment: public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }